# My jquery is not calling this button control in my mvc4 application?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, json.net

```
txt += '<tr><td><div id ="result1" ><div>' + Photo + '</div> <div ><div>' + data[i].ProductId + "</br> Name- " + data[i].Name + "</br> Description " + data[i].ShortDescription + ", </br>" + data[i].Price+'<div id="cartremove"><input id="Btnremove" type="submit" value="Remove" /></div>' + "</br>";
```

I called this button div in my jquery..but its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("#cartremove").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    debugger;
    alert('flag')
    });
```

Tell me the solution for this problem..

Comment: It seems you should [delegate the event](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

Comment: And as a side note, i see `i` in your code seems like a loop, so better use class instead of IDs as IDs must be unique!

Comment: Note you have invalid html. Your have 2 opening `<td>` tags but no closing `</td> and 5 opening `<div>` tags but only 2 closing `</div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use delegate the event.

```
$(document).on('click',"#cartremove", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    debugger;
    alert('flag');
});
```